# Faster image loading

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display about 5-8 images on my page, one by one, but I would like them to pre-load one and not loading them each time i switch to anohter image.

I have seen some examples where they have all images (hidden) on the page something like:

```
<a href=""><img id="img1" src="images/image1.png" class="image" alt="" /></a>
<a href=""><img id="img2" src="images/image1.png" class="image" alt="" /></a>
<a href=""><img id="img3" src="images/image1.png" class="image" alt="" /></a>
```

And the unhide the current image.

And what I have is one image that i change it's src attribute for path for new images from th array.

```
SwitchNextImage: function(){    
   var theimg=document.getElementById("imgContainer");                  

   this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex+ 1 == this.totalImageCount ? 0 : this.currentIndex + 1;
   theimg.src=this.slideimages[this.currentIndex].src;          
}
```

The first method is obviously faster loading. But requies static links.
My questions is how can I make my method more faster loading?

Comment: buy a faster internet connection? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upon loading the document you can create an array with `Image` objects. see [this article on techrepublic](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5214317.html)

Comment: This what i want to understand, if just create an Image object (and not render ) it's automatically loaded?

Answer (score 3):

You should look into image preloading.  You can achieve what you want through javascript by creating a new image object for each image:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "image2.png";
```

This will fetch the image and store it in the cache without actually displaying it on the page, so when you come to switching the `src` of your main image, the browser can fetch it from the cache.  Repeat this for all of your images and you should be set.

Comment: thank you both, knittl was first to answer so i will accept his answer.

Comment: @nemiss: no worries :-) That's usually how I accept answers too.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue before where my image galley would just freeze on random photos every time. I tried these two things, I created a custom JavaScript with an array that loaded the images and I tried Light Box library. There wasn't any difference in the speed. The images loaded slow in both cases.

I looked it up and found out that the cause to slow loading is probably. 
- Slow internet connection. 
- Image size/format. (jpg is recommended for photos)

So I did some research and I came up with the simple solution that **HQ photos are loaded faster when optimized for the web.** This can be done with Photoshop.

After optimizing the photos, the quality stayed great and my gallery is loading instantaneously.